# ASP.NET: How can I find my other row elements from LinkButton click?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, repeater, linkbutton

I have a `Repeater` with a `LinkButton` for each row. I want to be able to read the values of some other controls (such as a `Label`) that are in the same row as the `LinkButton`.  Here is the code I'm currently using, but im not sure what to put in my "Click" method for the linkbutton to get the values of the other controls in my row.

**Repeater ItemDataBound**

```
Private Sub Repeater_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater.ItemDataBound

   Dim oRow As xsdTable.MyDataTableRow
   Dim RemoveLinkButton As LinkButton

   RemoveLinkButton = e.Item.FindControl("RemoveLinkButton")
   AddHandler RemoveLinkButton.Click, AddressOf RemoveLinkButton_Click

   // Set other Controls Information   

End Sub
```

**RemoveLinkButton Click Event**

```
Public Sub RemoveLinkButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

    // Not sure what to do here to get the id for that row and identify the other 
    // controls to get the information from them...

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [`NamingContainer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.control.namingcontainer.aspx) property of the control to get the `RepeaterItem`:

```
Public Sub RemoveLinkButton_Click(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs)

    Dim control = DirectCast(sender, Control)
    Dim item = DirectCast(control.NamingContainer, RepeaterItem)
    ' now use FindControl to get the other controls in this item '

End Sub
```